# build error link.h:42:21: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory

Tags: urdf, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to perform the arm navigation tutorials. Therefore some packages have to be rosmaked. During compilation I constantly get this error:

home/wouter/ros/workspace/robot_model/urdf_interface/include/urdf_interface/link.h:42:21: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory

Indeed tinyxml.h is not in /include/urdf_interface/ and therefore I copied it from /home/wouter/ros/workspace/robot_model/colladadom/build/colladadom/dom/external-libs/tinyxml.h. Nevertheless I still get this error, does anyone has a solution for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11050/build-error-link.h:42:21:-fatal-error:-tinyxml.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Which arm_navigation tutorials are you trying to use?  For the electric arm_navigation tutorials there should be no need to compile code - just use the debians.  If you are trying to use the diamondback tutorials just use the diamondback debians.  If you need to compile code for some reason in order for us to help you will have to tell us what OS you are using, what versions you are trying to install - what portion from debians, which debians, and how you've overlayed the code to compile.  Given that you are using urdf_interface I gather that you are trying to use electric - just follow these instructions for ubuntu - http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu

tinyxml is included in the package tinyxml - you will not just be able to bring in a header file from some other location.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2